# Pen Drive is not able play audio in audio player after formated as FAT32

Tags: linux, audio, filesystems, iot, fat32

Firstly I made my pendrive as bootable and after finished the stuff i formatted it as FAT32 and feed the songs into it , then i plugged into mp3 player in car to play the songs but mp3 player can't able to play the songs even though ports are fine and mp3 works for another pendrive . How can i overcome with this problem..

Answer (score 0):

*STEP 1*

Convert your USB disk line from GPT to MBR using command line:

1. CMD - Run as admin
2. Type diskpart
3. Type list disk
4. Type Select disk [disk number]
5. Type clean
6. Type convert mbr

*STEP 2*

1. Right-click on Start button > Select Disk management
2. Select USB drive and right-click > Select new simple volume >
   Format type FAT32

Answer (score -1):

FAT32 should work fine with car stereo, you should try formatting it again

Comment: And pendrive is also fine it works normally in lap and computer

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same problem and I found the solution here https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/143010-what-usb-format-play-mp3-my-car-pioneer-stereo-player.html

Basically usb disk should be converted to MBR type and then formatted to FAT32.

Here is how to convert to MBR ->
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-gpt-disk-into-an-mbr-disk